# Prove that $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $Y$ is Hausdorff and $A$ is a closed subset of $X$

Tags: general-topology

> Part 1: Let $X$ be a topological space and $A$ a subset of $X$ . On $X \times \{0, 1\}$ define the partition composed of the pairs $\{(a, 0),(a, 1)\}$ for $a \in A$, and of the singletons $\{(x, i)\} $if $x \in X \setminus A$ and $i \in \{0, 1\}$. Let $ R$ be the equivalence relation defined by this partition, let $Y$ be the quotient space $(X \times \{0, 1\}) /R$ and let $p : X \times \{0, 1\} \rightarrow Y$ be the quotient map.
>
> (a) Prove that there exists a continuous map $ f : Y \rightarrow X$ such that $f \circ p(x, i) = x$ for every $ x \in X $ and $i \in \{0, 1\}$.
>
> (b) Prove that $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if $X$ is Hausdorff and $A$ is a closed subset of $X$.
>
> Part 2: Consider the above construction for $X = [0, 1]$ and $A$ an arbitrary subset of $[0, 1]$.
> Prove that $Y$ is compact. Prove that $K = p[X × \{0\}]$ and $L = p[X × \{1\}]$ are compact,
> and that $K \cap L$ is homeomorphic to $A$.

part 1a) attempt: try to prove that $f\circ p $ is continuous. So I need to show that if a set is closed in $X$, then it's closed in $X\times\{0,1\}$, which I would imagine is endowed with the product topology, in which both $\{0\}$ and $\{1\}$ are open (and closed). Hence, any closed set in $X$ would be closed in $X\times\{0,1\}$. As $f\circ p$ and $p$ are both continuous, it follows that so if $f$.

part 1b) no idea what strategy to use. I think $f\circ p$ is a homemorphism, but I'm not sure how that'd help. Also can't see how $A$ being closed would help.

part 2) $[0,1]\times\{0,1\}$ looks like it should be compact, as it's the union of two closed and bounded intervals in $\mathbb{R}$. But what about when I form the quotient space? And what about the last part?

Comment: Your notation $\{X \times 0,1\}$ should be $X \times \{0,1\}$.

Comment: Before you can prove anything in 1a, first *define* $f$ in the first place!

Comment: $f$ would map $(x,i)$ to $x$ and $\{(x,0),(x,1)\}$ to $x$.

Comment: As to 1b, you must mean that $Y$ is Hausdorff iff $X$ is Hausdorff and $A$ is closed? The statement as is seems absurd: $X$ being Hausdorff implies nothing about $A$?

Comment: yes - sorry, got them the wrong way round, should've double-checked before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define $f$ as in your comment (so for a class $c$ of the form $c = \{(x,i)\}$, where $x \notin A, i \in \{0,1\}$, define $f(c) = x$, and for a class $c$ of the form $c = \{(a,0),(a,1)\}$, where $ a \in A$, also define $f(c) = a$), we have that $f \circ p = \pi_1$, where $\pi_1 : X \times \{0,1\} \rightarrow X$ is the projection onto the first coordinate.

The universal property of the quotient map then shows that $f$ is continuous, as $\pi_1$ is. Short proof: if $O \subseteq X$ is open, $(\pi_1)^{-1}[O]$ is open by continuity of $\pi_1$, but this equals $p^{-1}[f^{-1}[O]]$. The *definition* of the quotient topology then says that $f^{-1}[O]$ is open, so $f$ is continuous.

For part 2, use that $p$ is continuous and $X \times \{0,1\}$ is compact. Ditto for $K$ and $L$. The only classes of $Y$ that have both upper and lower points are those with first coordinate in $A$, so the homeomorphism should be obvious.

Comment: Got it, thanks for your clear answer. Any hints for 1b?

Comment: Actually, I think I've got it. "$\Rightarrow$": use the contrapositive. Suppose two points $x_1,x_2\in X$ aren't separable. Then $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ aren't separable either, as if they were then the inverse images of their separated open neighbourhoods would be separated neighbourhoods of $x_1,x_2$ (from continuity of $f$). Next, suppose $A$ is not closed and consider points $a$ on the border of $A$. Consider the two (distinct) points $\{a,0\},\{a,1\}$. As $a$ is on the boundary of $A$, any open neighbourhood contains a point $b$ in $A$. Under $f$, it will map to a point which is in

Comment: the intersection of open neighbourhoods of $\{a,0\}$ and $f\{a,1\}$. "$\Leftarrow$": if $x,y$ are distinct and separable, then clearly so are $f(x)$ and $f(y)$. If $x\in X\backslash A$, then $\{x,0\}\neq\{(x,1)\}$. As $A$ is closed, $X\backslash A$ is open. Then just take the sets $X\backslash A\times \{0\}$ and $X\backslash A\times \{1\}$ as separating sets.

Comment: If you would let me know whether I've made any illegal assumptions / faulty deductions, I'd really appreciate it :)

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt As to the first, $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ might be the same point as $f$ is not 1-1. So you need to consider that case. I don't quite follow the reasoning why $A$ is closed? The other direction looks better. It's tricky to write down completely and correctly, but a good exercise in quotient topologies!

Comment: You're right, I didn't think about that. Ok, so if $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$, then they obviously aren't separable. If $f(x_1)\neq f(x_2)$, then they're not separable either (from the above argument).

Comment: Actually, I was using $f$ the wrong way around. I'll try writing a full answer now.

Comment: I've tried writing down an answer - any help with completing it?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to part 1b (attempt)

"$\Rightarrow$": consider the function $p:X\times \{0,1\} \rightarrow (X\times \{0,1\})/ R$, and suppose $X$ isn't Hausdorff. Take $(x_1,0)\neq (x_2,0)$ and there exist separated open sets $U,V$ containing $p(x_1,0)$ and $p(x_2,0)$ respectively. Then $p^{-1}(U),p^{-1}(V)$ are open in $X\times \{0,1\}$ by continuity of $p$, are separated and contain respectively $(x_1,0)$ and $(x_2,0)$, contadicting that $X$ is Hausdorff.

Now, suppose $A$ isn't closed. Take a point $a$ on the boundary of $A$, and consider $(a,0),(a,1)$ in $X\times \{0,1\}$. $p(a,0)\neq  p(a,1)$. I will show these points cannot be separated. *Intuitively, I need to use the fact that any open neighbourhood of $a$ contains a point $b\in A$, and that $p(b,0)=p(b,1)$, but I'm having difficulty articulating an argument.*

"$\Leftarrow$": if $(x,i_x),(y,i_y)$ are distinct and separable in $X \times \{0,1\}$, then clearly so are $p(x,i_x)$ and $p(y,i_y)$ in $(X\times \{0,1\})/ R$. If $x\in X\backslash A$, then $(x,0)\neq(x,1)$. As $A$ is closed, $X\backslash A$ is open. Then just take the sets $X\backslash A\times\{0\}$ and $X\backslash A\times\{1\}$ as separating sets.